Adding Custom column in OneDrive using Microsoft Graph API
We've been using Microsoft Graph APIs to retrieve data from OneDrive for Business. So far, we've obtained an Access Token to authenticate all subsequent connection requests with OneDrive. We've successfully accessed OneDrive Root Children data, downloaded documents from OneDrive, and fetched site details.
However, we are currently facing challenges in adding a custom column and setting its value in the OneDrive interface using the MS Graph API. We would appreciate any assistance you can provide on this matter. Additionally, we need guidance on how to implement remote event receivers in OneDrive to restrict actions such as renaming or deleting items.
Highlighting the critically challenge points: -

Facing challenges in adding a custom column and setting its value in the OneDrive interface using the MS Graph API.
Facing challenge to implement remote event receivers in OneDrive to restrict actions such as renaming or deleting items

